# How to change the featured Group/Organization on the home page?

Tags: python, jinja2, pylons, ckan, opendata

I'm using CKAN as a open data portal. I have completed setting up the CKAN instance and adding datasets, groups & organizations.

There is a featured group & a featured organization box on the home page. How can I show the group and the organization I want on the home page.

How to change these featured Group/Organization on the home page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `featured_groups` and `featured_orgs` config file settings: http://ckan.readthedocs.org/en/latest/maintaining/configuration.html#ckan-featured-groups

Comment: isn't there a easier way to get this done? like in the backend admin panel ?

Comment: There isn't, although it could be added to the admin panel of course (pull request welcome)